# L1 regression versus L2 regression

Tags: regression

I am trying to develop an intuition for why L1 regression is more expensive than L2 regression. Can somebody point me to some material that explains why this is the case

Comment: Because this doesn't point to material, it isn't an answer, but it may give you some insight: L1 regression of $n$ values against a constant fits *a* median (which might not be unique), whereas L2 regression fits the mean.  Finding the mean is obviously a $O(n)$ computation needing only $O(1)$ local storage.  Finding a median naively takes $O(n^2)$, requires $O(n\log(n))$ with the best available sorting algorithms, and actually needs only $O(n)$ time and $O(n)$ storage provided a clever algorithm is used.  That algorithm is considerably harder to code than one for the mean.

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12546/software-package-to-solve-l-infinity-norm-linear-regression/12564#12564

Comment: @whuber: A very simple randomized linear-time algorithm exists for finding a median. It can probably be written in a handful of lines of code in a modern programming language and is a very popular implementation of this in numerical-algorithm libraries, particularly because it is fully general (i.e., the same algorithm works for *all* order statistics). :)

Comment: @cardinal Yes, I'm aware of those algorithms.  But do you really think they are comparable in ease of coding and understanding to the simple loop that computes a mean?  And then consider the online problem: when you are fed a stream of numbers and need to update a running mean or median (or quantile), the difficulty of re-computing a median (compared to the mean) becomes apparent.  But I'm not claiming either problem is hard in any absolute sense...

Comment: @whuber: I agree that in an online situation, the difficulties mount. Viewing the L1 regression as an LP makes somewhat clearer why it might be more "expensive" than standard regression in many cases.

Comment: @cardinal: it is for a related question (oringinaly posted here: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/complexity-constants-in-median-computations-same-as-that-of-general-quantiles ) would you know anything about how the worst case complexity constants of the randomized linear time algorithm behave as a function of $\tau$, the targeted quantile? Thanks in advance,

Comment: It's not always true that L1 regression is more expensive than L2 regression, see Koenker and Portnoy (1997) http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.ss/1030037960

Comment: @user603: I think it should be pretty easy to show that the *worst* case performance is independent of the quantile for the randomized select algorithms. Indeed, consider the case where you happen to pick exactly the wrong element at random at each turn. Then the number of comparisons will be $O(n^2)$. But, this happens with very low probability (should be $\leq 2^n/n!$ I believe).

Comment: @user603: So, for example, if you pick the worst element at each time, then you have to do $n$ comparisons at the first iteration, $n-1$ at the second, $n-2$ at the third, etc., hence $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = O(n^2)$, so a leading constant of 1 suffices (at least in terms of comparison operations). :)

Comment: @cardinal; thanks for the comment. Maybe my question was not well formulated. I tought more of those algorithm with a linear worst case complexity  (say those shown here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm ).

Comment: @user603: Ah, ok. Since you said "randomized", I assumed you were speaking of the randomized selection algorithms. I would have to look more carefully at the deterministic ones which I am not as familiar with. I do recall that the one for the median is quite complex in comparison. You might look in Corman, et al., if you haven't already.

Answer (score 3):

L1 regularisation results in a penalised loss function with discontinuities in the derivatives, whereas L2 regularisation does not introduce discontinuities.  This means that when you perform gradient descent optimisation of the penalised loss there needs to be checks to see if a step goes over one of these discontinuities to make sure it is handled properly (hopefully the solution will lie on one of these discontinuities as this is what gives rise to the sparsity).  With L2 regularisation there are no such (additional) discontinuities, so there is no need to check for them, so it is generallly faster.  In the case of [kernel] ridge regression, you only need to solve a system of linear equations, which is why I normally use those methods rather than L1 regularisation these days.