# Compressed sensing: Optimization in $L_1$ norm and total variation with fourier coefficients

Tags: r, machine-learning, references, optimization

I'm reading the article [Robust Uncertainty Principles: Exact Signal Reconstruction from Highly Incomplete Frequency Information](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIT.2005.862083) (Candes, Romberg and Tao, 2004).

In this article they are talking about recovering the function $f$ whose fourier coefficients are known on some domain $\Omega$, by solving the following optimization problems:

$$ \min ||g||_{TV}  \space\space\space \text{s.t.} \space\space\space\hat{g}(w)=\hat{f}(w),w \in \Omega$$

and

$$ \min ||g||_{L_1}  \space\space\space \text{s.t.} \space\space\space\hat{g}(w)=\hat{f}(w),w \in \Omega$$

Can someone please give me a reference that suggests how to actually solve these optimization problems (that combines both $g$ and $\hat{g}$)?

A relevant R package would also be nice.

Comment: Have you looked at their own software package, [$\ell_1$-magic](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~justin/l1magic)? It may not be the most efficient implementation or algorithm, though. Note also that the fourier coefficients and the original function are related by a linear transformation, which can be approximated discretely by a DFT, making [linear programming](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12564/2970) packages a viable solution.

Comment: @cardinal: It seems to answer my quetions. Thanks!